# WiFi isn't working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

I have a HP ac123tx laptop. A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know much about Linux but I want to learn. But the Wifi is not connecting. It seems some driver is missing, I tried to install but it did not work.

My network card details:

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
13:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: I suspect that your issue is only `ant_sel`.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a known issue, trying to edit this file (first make a backup of it)

```
/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

add the following text:

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N
```

did this reboot

Comment: I searched for that file but it says that No such file or directory exists.

Comment: try:                                                                                                     sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git;
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git;
cd rtlwifi_new;
make;
sudo make install;
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf;
options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0

Comment: @ShubhamJangid That's normal - if you don't have this file by default you can create it

Comment: After doing all this I'm getting this:  **Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported**

Comment: Then use another editor (nano, vim, etc) to edit the file